Issue with communication between Spark Master and Spark Worker containers
I'm facing an issue when trying to set up communication between Spark Master and Spark Worker containers in a Docker environment. The goal is to use Spark for distributed processing in a cluster.
The structure of my project is as follows:
repo-project/
.
├── dns
├── docker
│   ├── cloudera
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── grafana
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── mongodb
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── spark
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── spark-worker
│       ├── docker-compose.yml
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── spark-worker.sh
├── docker-compose.yml
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── application.py
    ├── logs
    └── Tools
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
        │   ├── Tools.cpython-310.pyc
        │   └── Tools.cpython-311.pyc
        └── Tools.py


The docker-compose.yml files for the Spark Master and Spark Worker are defined in their respective directories (/docker/spark and /docker/spark-worker), respectively.
The issue arises when I try to start the containers with docker-compose up. The Spark Worker fails to connect to the Spark Master, and I receive the following error:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-master:7077
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master

I've tried various solutions, including:
Verifying if the containers are on the same Docker network. Ensuring that the Spark Master's address is correctly configured in the Spark Worker. Making sure that the Spark Master and Spark Worker containers are in the same Docker Compose.
However, the problem persists. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue of communication between the Spark Master and Spark Worker containers?
repo-project/docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  cloudera:
    build: ./docker/cloudera
    container_name: cloudera
    hostname: quickstart.cloudera
    ports:
      - "7180:7180"
      - "8088:8088"
      - "19888:19888"
      - "50070:50070"
      - "8888:8888"
      - "8082:8080"
      - "18088:18088"
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=cluster
      - SERVICES=hdfs,hive,spark
    networks:
      - network-docker


  spark-master:
    build: ./docker/spark
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "4040:4040"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_NAME=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_UI_PORT=8080
      - SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs
    depends_on:
      - cloudera
    networks:
      - network-docker

  spark-worker:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:latest
    container_name: spark-worker
    hostname: spark-worker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_MASTER_UI_PORT=8080
      - SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    networks:
      - network-docker

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - network-docker

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - network-docker

networks:
  network-docker:
    driver: bridge

repo-project/docker/spark/docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    build: .
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "4040:4040"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_NAME=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_UI_PORT=8080
      - SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs

  spark-worker:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:latest
    container_name: spark-worker
    hostname: spark-worker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G


repo-project/docker/spark/Dockerfile
FROM bde2020/spark-master:latest

COPY ./ /opt/spark-app/

# Exponha as portas necessárias
EXPOSE 8080 7077 4040

# Inicie o master do Spark
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"]



You should only have one compose file.

Why? @OneCricketeer

Assuming there's no typo in your post, you only need one Grafana, Mongo, Spark master, etc. All services can be in one file. And compose supports running replicas for multiple services natively. If you're trying to run multiple of the exact same service name in the same network, Docker would be confused... In any case, you can debug DNS by just running ping spark-master while entered into the Spark worker container. Or it's possible the spark master container is crashing and you should share its logs

I updated docker compose, can you help me? @OneCricketeer

Do you have the Spark master container logs? Is it starting okay? Do you need to override the CMD? https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark?tab=readme-ov-file#using-docker-compose
